# Vue-router обновляет маршрут, но не обновляет URL?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Есть компонент с name="activities". В маршруте также содержится `query: { date: '2019-01-02' }`. На самой странице есть элементы:

`router-link(:to="{ name: 'activities', query: query }")`

"Назад" и "Вперед", которые переключают день на 1 назад или вперед соответственно.

У компонента в методе `beforeRouteUpdate` прописана некая функция, которая выполняется при каждом клике на кнопку (то есть элемент обновляется, раз срабатывает данная функция).

Проблема - URL адрес как был с изначальным query, так и остается. При этом, если навести мышку на кнопку, то в углу экрана покажет ссылку с предыдущим или следующим днем (`/activities?date="2019-01-03"`). И если открыть в новой вкладке, то все ок. А вот если кликать в текущей вкладке, компонент обновляет данные, но URL в строке браузера остается тем же.

Answer (score -1):

Решение довольно простое - я просто забыл добавить вызов `next()` в метод `beforeRouteUpdate`.